# Java Application to push data to Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to built java application to Retrieve and save the data to Firebase Database.
I've followed [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and downloaded services account details and used the same in the project. I'm building a project on IntelliJ and added all the dependencies required. But I'm not able to save/retrieve any data to/from firebase.
While running the code I didn't get any error.

```
public class Database {
private static final String DATABASE_URL = "https://DATABASE-NAME.firebaseio.com";
private static final String FILE_NAME = "services-account-downloaded-file.json";
private static DatabaseReference database;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Initialize Firebase
    try {
        // [START initialize]
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
                .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(null)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        // [END initialize]
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: invalid service account credentials. See README.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }
    // Shared Database reference
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    startListeners();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void startListeners() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("user");
    ref.setValue("userdata", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: change ur database rules to read:true and write:true

Comment: Already added{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @PeterHaddad That's not required for firebase-admin. Initializing the SDK with a service account gives it full access to everything.

Answer (score 0):

To note: FirebaseCredential has been deprecated in favor of GoogleCredentials.

Try Changing your initialize block to:

```
       // [START initialize]
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
        .fromStream(serviceAccount)
        .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database"));

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    // [END initialize]
```

Comment: Deprecation just means that the API is going away some time, not that it doesn't work.